# How can we provide title on options of select in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, title, ui-select2

I m using angularjs. Now i want to keep title on my options of select of html. How can i use there..I have my code here as.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="col-md-12 hkg-nopadding" ui-select2="{allowClear:     true}" ng-model="name" id="selectName" name="selectName">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option ng-repeat="name in names" value="{{name.id}}" title=
            "{{name.text}}">{{name.text.length > 50 ? name.text.substring(0, 50) + '...' : name.text}}</option>
        </select>
```

Here title tag is not getting applied.Please help.!

Comment: show the json structure as welll as controller

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create fully accessible nested dropdown lists using WAI-ARIA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350634/how-to-create-fully-accessible-nested-dropdown-lists-using-wai-aria)

Answer (score 0):

Use [aria-label](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/accessibility#common-accessibility-patterns) rather than the title attribute:

> Relying on the title attribute is currently discouraged as many user agents do not expose the attribute in an accessible manner as required by this specification (e.g. requiring a pointing device such as a mouse to cause a tooltip to appear, which excludes keyboard-only users and touch-only users, such as anyone with a modern phone or tablet).

**References**

- [HTML Spec: The title attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#the-title-attribute)
- [WAI-ARIA RDF Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/rdf_model.svg)

Answer (score 0):

If your json object is correct it should work normally.
You can share more about what you do If you don't mind.